# adding the cwd / pwd / (.) to the path in powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

So I have a program I'd like to run in Windows PowerShell. In cmd I just type in `script.cmd` and it'll run the script. In PowerShell I apparently have to do `./script.cmd`.

BASH behaves similarly by default. To change BASH's behavior you need to do `export PATH=$PATH:.` and then `script.sh` will work instead of just `./script.sh`.

My question is...  how can I make `script.cmd` work in PowerShell? Do I have to do something similar to `export PATH=$PATH:.`? I did `echo $PATH` in PowerShell but that didn't output anything..

Comment: note that searching in the current directly poses some security threats. That's why PowerShell went the bash way, and the new DLL search functions in Win32 APIs also removes the current folder from the search list by default

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, read `get-help about_command_precedence` to see how this works.

Next, type `$env:path` to view your current PATH.

You can append a directory to the PATH like this: `$env:path += ";C:\Scripts"`

You can also append the current directory to the PATH like this: `$env:path += ";."`

`get-item env:` will show you all the environment variables.

Comment: `get-help about_command_precedence` gives me a `get-help : Get-Help could not find about_command_precedence in a help file in this session.` error. Everything else worked. Thanks!

Comment: That's easy to fix. Open PowerShell as admin, then use `update-help` to update from the internet.

Comment: `Update-Help` failed for me with some inscrutable errors.  `-Force` didn't help.  Administrator didn't help.  `Update-Help -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` did work though.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it permanetly, this is what I do.

(And instead of adding . to the path, I'll try to add the current directory you're in right now)

You can for example, edit the registry yourself.

```
$oldpath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).path
$newpath = "$oldpath;$($pwd.Path)"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $newPath
#final check
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).Path
```

Of course you need Admin Rights for that one. So let's find another way if you are not admin, and powershell gives you another way to do this, like this:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";$($pwd.Path)", "User")
```